# Query to retrieve only record for each user for last date entered

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2014

If I had a table like this:

```
Username    Comment    Date
-------------------------------    
   X        test1      1-1-2015      
   X        test2      1-3-2015      
   X        test3      1-6-2015      
   Y        test1      1-4-2015      
   Y        test2      1-5-2015      
   Y        test3      1-9-2015
```

and I need to get an output result like the below

```
Username    Comment    Date
----------------------------
    X       test3      1-6-2015      
    Y       test3      1-9-2015
```

Output:

only retrieve record for X & Y based on the last date (get user name & comment for the last date that entered)

Is there is any way by using SQL Server 2014 to get result like this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Great timing 3x the same answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number` to select the most recent comment per username

```
select * from (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by username order by date desc) rn
  from mytable
) t1 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
      Username, Comment, [Date],
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
)
SELECT
    Username, Comment, [Date]
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
```

This selects only the most recent entry for each `Username`

Also: be aware that `Date` is a **reserved keyword** in T-SQL and it **should not** be used for your own column names! Try to use something more meaningful - like `CommentDate` or something!